# Apache: Invalid command ProxyRequests

Tags: apache

I setup a new Vhost for jenkins:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ci.company.com
    ServerAlias ci
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

...which uses proxy and when i restart apache I get error like this:

```
Invalid command 'ProxyRequests', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Comment: by the way my config ```    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/ //here is different ```

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You should enable proxy. Run a command:

```
 sudo a2enmod proxy
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: If you happen to be using WebMin, you can go into: Servers > Apache Webservers > Global Configuration > Configure Apache Modules. Then in the second column (usually), you will find a module named 'proxy'. Check it on, then scroll to the bottom and hit 'Enable Selected Modules". This will turn on proxy and restart apache at the same time.

Comment: While you are at it, enable proxy_http. You need them both to get this working!

Comment: how to do this in centos ??

Comment: @TrooddoN-Mike I think it should be `sudo a2enmod proxy`, anyway +1

Comment: Im getting this sudo: a2enmod: command not found on mac, do  you know how to enable it?

Comment: I needed to add `sudo a2enmod proxy_html` too

Answer (score 16):

```
 sudo a2enmod proxy
 sudo a2enmod proxy_http
 systemctl restart apache2
```

If you don't enable proxy_http you get this error in the apache error log file for the site:

> AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL / (scheme 'http').
> If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy
> submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

This error in general can be found with this message after a new installation with an old vhost:

> Invalid command 'ProxyPreserveHost', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 15):

proxy module must be disable.
Enable it using below command

```
a2enmod proxy
```

If you don't have access to root, you can use

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
```

After that restart apache server using

```
service apache2 reload
```